# Run Shell Command via ffmpeg arguments

Tags: ffmpeg

Is there any known way to run a shell command via a command line argument to `ffmpeg`? Using ffmpeg's code only, not trying to use the shell its being invoked from (shell metacharacters, etc).

I looked through the man page but didn't find anything promising.

Comment: Could you add a use-case? Since `ffmpeg` is not a command interpreter, your question makes very little sense to me.

Comment: I'm looking for vulnerabilities. I've gotten to this point, if theres any way to perform what I've described via the ffmpeg arguments only then I've found a remote code execution bug in a web application.